# Make User Login Act as Administrator

Tags: windows-xp, administrator

Some of the computers at my place of work are still using XP (Replacements are in the works). Often I have to install printer drivers or software (*a privilege denied to the average user on our network*) etc for users in the company, but XP will often force you to log off and log back in as an admin to perform certain tasks (*where 'Run as admin' is not an option*).

To cut a long story short, a year or so ago I witnessed a colleague open `cmd` and perform some operations to temporarily grant the user account that was logged in admin rights so that they didn't need to relog to perform a certain task.

Since then this colleague has left us, and I have been unable to find any information on how this might be done. Is anyone aware of any procedures like this, and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/07/24/makemeadmin-temporary-admin-for-your-limited-user-account.aspx

Comment: @kmarsh - That certainly fits the specification, even if the new cmd window has to be used to perform all actions. If you write that up as an answer with a brief description of using it etc, i'll give you an up-vote (and accept if no better answer come in soon).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open XP's "Help and Support Center".
2. In the Search box type: ADMINISTRATOR , and hit enter.
3. Click on the task titled: "Start a program as an administrator".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I'm not sure you read the question. I stated where *"Run as admin' is not an option"*, and you provided me with [how to run as admin](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_runas.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: This solution does not use "run as Administrator" for the sole reaon that does NOT exist in Windows XP.  You can run any program as another user using the command line including the `Administrator` account.  This command is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a flaw in Windows (possibly still unpatched in XP) that allowed you to schedule an Administrator level cmd prompt from a normal users cmd prompt. From there you can killtask explorer.exe and launch a new one on the administrator cmd and grant yourself admin privaledges. He might've been using that.